# Redirect url with question mark and other characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How would i redirect this url to www.example.com using a htaccess file.

```
used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item?000172:compost-turner
```

Would this work?

```
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item?000172:compost-turner?$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Would the ? cause an issue in the old url?

Comment: What are those sample URLs you want to rewrite using this rule? Also do you want URL to change in browser or want silent rewrite only.

Comment: Ive updated my question if that's easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

The question mark should represent a query string, thus you would have to make write a condition to detect the query string. This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item$
ReWriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^000172:compost-turner$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Edit:

With a huge bunch or URLs you can use the "OR" flag or perhaps even try something on the server side. It would be a pain but I don't know any other solution with a huge amount of links.

```
RewriteEngine On

# %{THE_REQUEST} format as follows
# GET /used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item?000172:compost-turner HTTP/1.1
# important notes: 
#     escape ? with( \?)
#     space after url (\ )
#     each line has [NC,OR] flags for case insensitive and checks this condition or the next
#     last Cond line does not have the OR flag

ReWriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+\ /used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item\?000172:compost-turner\ .*$ [NC,OR]
ReWriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+\ /anoterURL\?querystring\ .*$ [NC,OR]
ReWriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+\ /lastURL\?with-no-OR-at-end\ .*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If you wish to a a mass edit, I suggest using [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)

- Paste all links with one link per line
- Turn word wrap off
- Select a ? in a URL
- In the menu, Find > Quick Find All (to select all ?s on the page)
- Press left cursor arrow

  - type the \
- Press the End key to go the end of all lines

  - type \ .*$ [NC,OR]
- Press the Home key to go the beginning of all lines

  - type ReWriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+\
- Edit the last row to remove the ,OR

Comment: What if I had multiple instances of that type of url, would I have to create a query string for each? seems a lot of work?

Comment: Comes dow to what pattern you are trying to match. If the query string is not important then you can leave out the ReWriteCond line looking at the query string. If it is needed, then we have to see what are the patterns it is supposed to match.

Comment: I've put in my whole list of rewrite urls in the [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoAta?editors=100). Sorry if it's alot just wanted to show you what I'm dealing with!

Comment: check the edit above. I don't think there is an easy way

Comment: What if I need each url to redirect to a different url not just http://www.example.com/. For example /used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item\?000172:compost-turner\ redirects to http://www.example.com/machines, /news/news-item?open-days-a-huge-success\ redirects to http://www.example.com/news etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} 000172:compost-turner [NC]
RewriteRule ^used-machinery/en/other/used-machinery-item/?$ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php/).*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```